# Show Image Captions When Hovering

Tags: javascript, html, caption

I'm trying to use javascript to show the caption of an image only when it's being hovered, and have a default caption displayed when no image is hovered.

```
<ul class="logos">
    <li class="image-1"></li>
    <li class="image-2"></li> 
    <li class="image-3"></li> 
    <li class="image-4"></li> 
    <li class="image-5"></li>  
</ul>

<div class="captions">
    <p>Default caption</p>
    <p>This is a caption for the first logo</p>
    <p>This is a caption for the second logo</p>
    <p>This is a caption for the third logo</p>
    <p>This is a caption for the fourth logo</p>
    <p>This is a caption for the fifth logo</p>
</ul>
```

Any advice on how I could implement such an effect with javascript?

Comment: Can you not use alt="Caption"?

Comment: I could probably use title=, but I don't know how I'd implement to fit the requirements of the desired effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a better way to structure your page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    // sets the caption for the clicked img
    function caption(img){
       // finds the element with an id="caption"
       var ctrl = document.getElementById("caption");

       // sets the text of the element = the alt property of the img
       alert(img.alt);
       ctrl.innerText = img.alt;

       // sets the css display property = block (shows the element)
       ctrl.style.display = "block";

       // hides the defaultCaption element
       document.getElementById("defaultCaption").style.display = "none";
    }

    // shows the defaultCaption and hides the caption div
    function clearCaption() {
       document.getElementById("defaultCaption").style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById("caption").style.display = "none";
    }
 </script>

<ul class="logos">
    <!--
       alt : an alternative text description for an image
       onmouseover : event handler that fires as the mouse moves over image
       onmouseout : event handler that fires as the mouse moves off the image
    -->
    <li><img class="image-1" alt="caption text" onmouseover="caption(this)" onmouseout="clearCaption()"/></li>
    <li><img class="image-2" alt="caption text" onmouseover="caption(this)" onmouseout="clearCaption()"/></li>
    <li><img class="image-3" alt="caption text" onmouseover="caption(this)" onmouseout="clearCaption()"/></li>
    <li><img class="image-4" alt="caption text" onmouseover="caption(this)" onmouseout="clearCaption()"/></li>
    <li><img class="image-5" alt="caption text" onmouseover="caption(this)" onmouseout="clearCaption()"/></li>
</ul>

<div id="caption" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="defaultCaption">default caption text</div>
```

UPDATED:
Hadn't spotted that the image tags were malformed? - I've rewritten it as a list of images.

If your want li elements then change `alt` to `title` (in the elements and the code).

Comment: Wow! I'll give that a go and report back.

Comment: I'll tack on a jQuery method for you to have a look at, but I'd recommend you get your head around the basics first

Comment: Reporting back. I kept the class attribute appended to the li and replaced alt with title, because I have no need for image tags. It works flawlessly. Thanks not only for your help, but for breaking it down to help me understand what's actually going on.

Answer (score 1):

You even do not need JavaScript. You can achieve it via CSS.

See it in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/n6wTr/

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="logos">
        <li class="image i1">
            <p class="caption">1st caption</p>
        </li>
        <li class="image i2">
            <p class="caption">2nd caption</p>        
        </li> 
        <li class="image i3">
            <p class="caption">3rd caption</p>                
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.container {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 2em;
}

li.image p.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

li.image:hover p.caption {
    display: block;
}​
```